# Stocks that match the criteria of the "intelligent investor"

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets

Warning! Noob investor.

I am new to investing and trying to learn how to make effective trades.

I recently started listening to the "The intelligent investor"

The book offers various starter points on which stocks to pick.
For Eg. they are summarized nicely here: https://cabotwealth.com/daily/value-investing/benjamin-grahams-value-stock-criteria/

However, I am having difficulty to filter stocks that fall in this category.

To be specific I am looking for a tool where in I can enter my requirements
For Eg. Large Cap, tech sector, P/E = xx, Dividends = Yes, Debt = No, etc

The brute force method would be to get a list of all companies in S&P500 and check the details of each one of them individually but I am sure there must be a better way.

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome new user.  As mentioned below, it's easy to find such tools, just google.   But be warned that this "system", like every single "system", is utterly hopeless.

Comment: @Fattie But then I must chose some underlying principle for buying stocks. If not this then can you recommend some other method?

Comment: for sure, an index fund.  They always and every time beat stock pickers.

Comment: To @Fattie 's last point. "On average" this is absolutely true. Consider that at a casino, every night there's some guy who walks away with a huge win. Not the same guy every night. Some tiny fraction of stock pickers will beat the market. On average they lag the market by quite a bit.

Comment: *"Some tiny fraction of stock pickers will beat the market"*  Quite right, JTP. Indeed it is even worse than that.  In a *given* year of the about ~50,000 stock pickers of all types (funds, etc) as you say a handful beat the average.  **BUT** they never, ever repeat.  It's ***not*** the case that "there are only 1 or 2 good ones that always beat the market".  Quite simply, they all (utterly and completely) fail.  Randomly, 1 or 2 beat the market in one year only.

Comment: @Fattie I have read several people recommending something similar. But wouldn't index funds limit your gain. For eg. In any given quater, not all companies in DJIA or S&P500 will show growth, so the returns would be stunted. On the other hand if we invest in specific equities the % gain can be much higher

Comment: hi @john - in your example, instead of an index fund, you try stocks A, B, C and D.  It could well be that A, B, C and D all ...... plummet.

Comment: @john , I would urge you to get one of those totally free "trial" accounts where you try your hand on the markets with virtual money.  Give it a go for 12 months and come back!

Comment: @Fattie There are actually quite a few stock pickers that consistently beat the market.... Also beating the market isn't actually all that hard (just pick the top 450 companies from the S&P 500). Your advice (especially to a novice) is obviously not wrong. But to suggest it's not possible is ignorant.

Comment: @xyious .. *"There are actually quite a few stock pickers that consistently beat the market"* - that is FANTASTIC NEWS, can you definitely tell me who ?  thanks !

Comment: @john - Dalbar has produced studies that compare aver investor return vs the market. “For the twenty years ending 12/31/2015, the S&P 500 Index averaged 9.85% a year. A pretty attractive historical return. The average equity fund investor earned a market return of only 5.19%.“ So having spent much of my life ‘lagging’ the market by about .02% I’m pretty happy.

Comment: @Fattie The obvious example is Buffett. There's a few more but they don't tend to get a lot of media coverage because they don't make flashy moves and the media on the whole is far more short term focused.

Comment: @xyious Hmm, headlines, "Warren Buffett has lost nearly $10 billion in seven days." "Warren Buffett Is 2020’s Biggest Money Loser"  "This year shows what Buffett, himself, has long said: It's hard to beat the S&P 500."  In trading circles Buffet is seen as having made one spectacular bet (on Insurance) that paid off great for a couple decades, and that's about it. Lately he's an epic loser. Unfortunately I don't know any other examples of anyone beating the index, even for awhile like Buffet. (I don't really follow the mass media.)

Comment: (now $20 b !)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People use tools called "stock screeners", there are plenty available all over the internet and many brokerage firms have their own tool for customers as well.

Comment: Could you give a few free examples?

Comment: @john https://www.google.com/search?q=stock+screeners

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as it is a general concept. @base64